# My MS Access query is too complex

Tags: ms-access

I've recently created a large MS Access database and i'm trying to build some logic into it. However I get an error message saying the query is too complex. After doing some debugging it seems like 4 switch statements work fine but more then 6 cause a problem (example below). My version has 100+ statements and should add an extra column based on the value in HOSTNAMEDB.NAME.

***Example***

```
SELECT 

  ...

  SWITCH (
    HOSTNAMEDB.NAME LIKE "serverA*", "Customer A",
    HOSTNAMEDB.NAME LIKE "serverB*", "Customer B",
    HOSTNAMEDB.NAME LIKE "serverC*", "Customer C",
    HOSTNAMEDB.NAME LIKE "serverD*", "Customer D",
  ) AS Customer,

  ...

FROM

  ... etc
```

What is the best way to work around this? Or am I reaching the limits of MS Access?

Comment: It sounds like maybe you should make another table that maps `server` patterns to `Customer`s, and `join` to that.

Comment: The only limit I know of, is that of 255 columns per query. I could imagine this switch statement taking up 1 column per switch, but there's no _max 4 switch statements per switch_, of course.  The approach by underscore_d sounds right, but in this specific example, you might also use `"Customer " & Mid(HOSTNAMEDB.NAME, 7, 1)`

Comment: I guess the best way is to make alot of JOIN's with LIKE's right?

Comment: That's not what underscore_d is saying. You should have a join with a single like, or no like at all, and a separate table translating the separate `HOSTNAMEDB.NAME`s to customer names.

Comment: Do you have the name of this method so I can search on google for some query examples. That would help alot because i havent worked with translating tables before.

Comment: Just to add; HOSTNAMEDB.NAME is not the only one. Also have HOSTNAMEDB.GROUP and HOSTNAMEDB.IP